# After Grub, if i choose Ubuntu, it's not loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2

Windows 10 is default OS but, when I choose Ubuntu (20.04 LTS), it's not loading at all. Ubuntu is installed on a separate NVMe drive and drive is all fine:

[image: Partition Layout]

After choosing Ubuntu, it goes further and then black screen. There is a blinking cursor in the upper left corner of the screen, and that's it. What could be the issue? During last 3 months - I have switched from Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB card to Nvidia 1050Ti 4 GB card. Even after that switch Ubuntu always worked fine. What could be the issue?

I haven't logged into Ubuntu for around 3+ months and during last few months there had been number of Windows updates. I am not upgrading my Windows 10 to Windows 11.

**Update 1:**
Tried boot-repair after live-usb boot("Try Ubutu) - it stated that boot-repair worked fine but when tried to reboot once again in Ubuntu...the same black screen with cursors blinking.
Here is the [pastebin location](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jNgyXVgyFW/) from boot-repair
These were the further instructions

**Boot successfully repaired.**

Please write on a paper the following URL:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jNgyXVgyFW/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

```
You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p2/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

**Update 2**
I am able to boot via recovery mode but subsequent boot into Ubuntu Linux is not working. I can only boot into ubuntu via recovery mode.

**Update 3**
Fresh install of Ubuntu Linux. Even this didn't work out. There were issues in terms of nvidia graphics driver install. Recovery mode install and tried "install broken packages" and got this error.
[image]
So finally I went into additional drivers and started using nvidia-470(proprietary and tested) driver. It's working fine after that.
[image]

Comment: Have you booted with a Live USB and tried to repair the Grub installer? One of the Windows updates may have clobbered something ... 

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Often black screen is booting, but then video issue. If UEFI boot can you press escape right after vendor screen & before grub menu should appear to get grub menu & use second entry or recovery mode?  If not: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @matigo-worth trying...will do that. Thanks

Comment: @oldfred. Ubuntu was running on this system for at least 4+ years. Few months back, i gave better GPU to my son and took his GPU-both NVidia...even after that Ubuntu was working fine. I was not login into ubuntu for at least last 3 months and thus something happened during that time

Comment: Did you install different nVidia driver? You have to purge old drive before installing new one or you get conflicts & black screen type issues. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362351&p=13649946#post13649946

Comment: @oldfred-I believe the same driver works even if I am using 1060 or 1050Ti-isn't it the case? I downgraded from 1060 6GB to 1050Ti 4GB but both from nvidia but different manufacturers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to change of graphics card in my Computer which caused this issue. Initially already installed nvidia graphics card driver worked for my new Nvidia 1050Ti 4GB graphics card(my old one was Nvidia 1060 6GB) but later I was getting only black screen with blinking cursor(it was not grub or boot issue so boot-repair didn't worked). Several attempts to fix the nvidia graphics driver via recovery mode failed. So finally I installed ubuntu Linux again(as it's less time to do that and then started using proprietary and tested nvidia-479 from additional drivers. It's been fixed now.